# How to integrate Expresso and Control M Jobs with splunk?

Tags: splunk, control-m, splunk-query, expresso-store, expresso

We have requirement to update the Expresso and Control-M scheduled job completion status in Splunk which will useful for live job monitoring. I have searched in SPlunk app and not able to find any app related to Expresso & Control-M. Is there anyway to integrate these into splunk ?

Answer (score 0):

If Expresso & Control-M produce log files or stream data then it will be super easy to add to Splunk. First off, is your Splunk app installed on the same server as Control-M? How much data do you anticipate ingesting each day through Splunk?